# AWS IAM access to s3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have one S3 bucket for which I need to deny access for all users and allow access to a specific IAM role.

I followed the doc provided by AWS. I am able to do for users but when I do for role, this does not work. Can anybody help?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

I tried the following code in S3 bucket policy.It cause access deny for all users including lambda role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::relambda",
                "arn:aws:s3:::relambda/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:roleId": [
                        "KDCNKWDCKQWCLQKC:*",
                        "5371235537537"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have nothing in `Principal`.

Please refer/use below policy.

An IAM user has a unique ID starting with AIDA that you can use for this purpose. To find this unique ID:

With the AWS CLI installed, open a command prompt or shell.
Run the command: aws iam get-user -–user-name USER-NAME
In the output, look for the userId string, which will begin with AIDAEXAMPLEID.
When you have identified the userId string, you can place it in the “aws:userId” condition array, as shown in the following example.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*",
            "AIDAEXAMPLEID",
            "111111111111"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, you gave me solution for user.I need for IAM role.User I am able to make work but it does not work for role.

Comment: What is the difference between your code and my code

Answer (score 0):

This should deny access to everyone except for the role using the `NotPrincipal` key.

```
{
  "Id": "DenyRoleAccess",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAllRole",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
      ],
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT-ID:role/ROLE-NAME"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Deny access by default
- Allow access for a specific IAM role

Fortunately, the default for all Amazon S3 buckets is to deny access by default, so this one is automatically met!

To permit access for a specific role, use a **Bucket Policy** like this:

```
{
  "Id": "AllowRoleAccess",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRole",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/ROLE-NAME"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There are also other settings you can use to limit it to a specific EC2 instance that is using a role.

Comment: Hi, You mentioned that s3 has by default deny access.I created S3 bucket and removed read,write operation and which is applied for only root account.Not for all

Comment: Buckets by default have no Bucket Policy, therefore they do not grant access. However, IAM Users and Roles can grant access to a bucket, even if the bucket has no access policy. Therefore, the above can also be achieved by putting permissions on the Role, with no Bucket Policy.

Comment: But without bucket policy in a fresh new bucket, I am able to access.There is no restriction.

Comment: That is because the IAM user you are using has S3 permissions.

Comment: Please understand my requirement, I want to restrict access to a specific bucket for the users who have full s3 access too. And want to give permission to a specific role, so that role can read.

Comment: But if you want to give a specific role Read access and you want to Deny access to everyone else, how are you going to put content into the Bucket?

Comment: I made that role as "not principal"  and denied for every one, but this is no working.